# Unable to access URL without trailing slash on NGINX

Tags: angular, nginx, nginx-location, nginx-config, trailing-slash

I have deployed my Angular 8 app on NGINX inside a subdirectory named test folder.

The app can be accessed successfully if the URL contains of a trailing slash.
E.g. www.example.com/test/
However, if it is accessed through www.example.com/test then it will load until it hits error 504.

Here is the code in my nginx config file.

```
location /test {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /test/index.html;
}
```